# Broken link to framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How i can fix broken framework link in libPMAnalytics-r91.a. Actually i download an application it is not compiling for simulator but working on device. In order to fix it i set the architecture to armv6 and armv7. Now it is compiling but libPMAnalyics-91.a has broken link to framework. This application is using Facebook old sdk(2009).

```
: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/igzzone/Desktop/Delete  /5/MouseWait(DisneyLand)/Classes/Classes'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Beacon", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MouseWaitAppDelegate.o
"_objc_exception_extract", referenced from:
  -[BeaconDatabase createTablesIfNeeded] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewSubBeaconWithName:timeSession:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase updateLocationWithLatitude:longitude:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endSubBeaconWithName:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase beaconsToSend] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  ...
"_objc_exception_try_exit", referenced from:
  -[BeaconDatabase createTablesIfNeeded] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewSubBeaconWithName:timeSession:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase updateLocationWithLatitude:longitude:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endSubBeaconWithName:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase beaconsToSend] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  ...
  "_objc_exception_try_enter", referenced from:
  -[BeaconDatabase createTablesIfNeeded] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase startNewSubBeaconWithName:timeSession:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase updateLocationWithLatitude:longitude:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endBeacon] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase endSubBeaconWithName:] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  -[BeaconDatabase beaconsToSend] in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  ...
  ".objc_class_name_NSAssertionHandler", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMReachability.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Database.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMReachability.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMJSONUtils.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFoundationObject.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Database.o)
  ...
   ".objc_class_name_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
 ".objc_class_name_NSMutableDictionary", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
      pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
   ".objc_class_name_NSNumber", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(BeaconDatabase.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
     ".objc_class_name_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMReachability.o)
      ".objc_class_name_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
   pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMReachability.o)
     ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
  .objc_class_name_PMReachability in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMReachability.o)
  .objc_class_name_PMFBSession in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
  .objc_class_name_PMFBXMLHandler in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
  .objc_class_name_Beacon in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  .objc_class_name_PMFBRequest in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
  .objc_class_name_PMJSONUtils in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMJSONUtils.o)
  .objc_class_name_PMFoundationObject in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFoundationObject.o)
  ...
   ".objc_class_name_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
 ".objc_class_name_NSTimer", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSHTTPCookieStorage", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
    ".objc_class_name_NSURL", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBSession.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
   ".objc_class_name_NSNull", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMJSONUtils.o)
   ".objc_class_name_NSCharacterSet", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDictionary", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBXMLHandler.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(PMFBRequest.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSException", referenced from:
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Beacon.o)
  pointer-to-literal-objc-class-name in libPMAnalytics-r91.a(Database.o)
```